# Change of variables in an expression involving differentials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I'm trying to derive Maxwell-Boltzmann's distribution using the statistics of the classical canonical ensemble. Doing some operations, I have found out that the probability that a molecule of a gas has a position between $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{r}+d^3\boldsymbol{r}$ and momentum between $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{p}+d^3\boldsymbol{p}$ is given by $(1)$:

$$P(\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{p}) d^{3} \boldsymbol{r} \space d^{3} \boldsymbol{p}=\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\beta}{2 \pi m}\right)^{3 / 2} e^{-\beta \varepsilon} d^{3} \boldsymbol{r} \space d^{3} \boldsymbol{p}  \tag{1}$$

where $\boldsymbol{r}=(x,y,z)$, $d^{3} \boldsymbol{r}=d x \space d y \space d z$, $\boldsymbol{p}=(p_{x}, p_{y}, p_{z})$, and $d^{3} \boldsymbol{p}=d p_{x} \space d p_{y} \space d p_{z}$.

I would like to derive the probability in terms of the velocity, $P(\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{v})$, from the expression $(1)$. However, I'm getting a wrong result just by replacing $\boldsymbol{p}$ by $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $d^3 \boldsymbol{p}$ by $d^3\boldsymbol{v}$... Could please anyone give me a hint about how should this kind of change of variables be done?

Comment: If the mass of all particles are the same can you not just take out the mass as a constant? I.e. $d^3p\rightarrow m^3d^3v$. That's how I've seen it done.

Comment: I tried that, but on the LHS how could I get $P(\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{v})$?

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable will have to help you, I don't follow your derivation, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new probability function $\tilde{P}$ that gives the probability to find the particle within $d^3 x \,d^3v$ as
$$
(\text{probability within } d^3x\, d^3v)=\tilde{P}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}) \,d^3 x \,d^3v.
$$

Since this is just a change of variables, the probabilities must be the same:
$$
\tilde{P}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}) \,d^3 x \,d^3v = P(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}) \,d^3 x \,d^3p.
$$
Now substitute in the RHS $\mathbf{p}\to m\mathbf{v}$ (both in the argument of $P$ as in the differential) to find
$$
\tilde{P}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}) \,d^3 x \,d^3v = P(\mathbf{r}, m\mathbf{v})m^3 \,d^3 x \,d^3v,
$$
and since the differentials are now the same,
$$
\tilde{P}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}) = m^3 P(\mathbf{r}, m\mathbf{v}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you define $P(r,p)$ as the *probability* that you'll find a molecule with position between $r$ and $r + d^3r$ and momentum within $p$ and $p + d^3p$, what's true is that
$$P(r,p) = \frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\beta}{2\pi m}\right)^{3/2}d^3r d^3 p$$
*without* the differentials on the LHS. Think of it this way: if you were to just consider the position of the molecule in the container of volume $V$, the probability you find it in any box of side length $dr$ is just
$$P(r) = \frac{dr^3}{V}$$
since that's the fraction of the volume you're considering. The probability is infinitesimal, and it should be, since you're only considering an infinitesimal piece of the phase space. Now you should find that the change of variables $p \to mv$ produces the desired result.

Comment: OP defined $P(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}) \, d^3 x\, d^3p$ as the probability to find a particle within the volume $d^3x \, d^3 p$ in phase space. $P$ is a probability by phase space volume.

Comment: That's fair, but if you'd like $P(r,p)$ to be the probability density function instead, as in eq. (1), when you change variables you need to multiply by a suitable Jacobian factor (in this case $m^{3}$, see e.g. [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)). AFAIK the only reason to keep the differentials in the equations is to remember this rule.